# .NET MAUI Media Picker for Windows return null

Tags: .net, windows, media, picker, maui

I used MS documentation to capture image from camera which working for android but windows always return null, it do not open Camera as well. Does anyone is able to get it working?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/device-media/picker?tabs=windows

Comment: please read [ask] before posting.  Your post does not contain any code illustrating what you are doing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is currently a bug in .NET MAUI https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7660 and ultimately in WinUI: https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues/1034

We're working to get it fixed!

In the meanwhile, there is a workaround if you implement some code yourself:

```cs
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.Media.Capture;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.System;
using Microsoft.Maui.Platform;
using WinRT.Interop;

public class CameraCaptureUI
{
    private LauncherOptions _launcherOptions;

    public CameraCaptureUI(MediaPickerOptions options)
    {
        var hndl = WindowStateManager.Default.GetActiveWindow().GetWindowHandle();

        _launcherOptions = new LauncherOptions();
        InitializeWithWindow.Initialize(_launcherOptions, hndl);

        _launcherOptions.TreatAsUntrusted                   = false;
        _launcherOptions.DisplayApplicationPicker           = false;
        _launcherOptions.TargetApplicationPackageFamilyName = "Microsoft.WindowsCamera_8wekyb3d8bbwe";
    }

        public async Task<StorageFile> CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode mode)
{
        var extension = mode == CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo ? ".jpg" : ".mp4";

        var currentAppData = ApplicationData.Current;
        var tempLocation = currentAppData.LocalCacheFolder;
        var tempFileName = $"CCapture{extension}";
        var tempFile = await tempLocation.CreateFileAsync(tempFileName, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
        var token = Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.SharedStorageAccessManager.AddFile(tempFile);

        var set = new ValueSet();
        if (mode == CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo)
        {
            set.Add("MediaType", "photo");
            set.Add("PhotoFileToken", token);
        }
        else
        {
            set.Add("MediaType", "video");
            set.Add("VideoFileToken", token);
        }

        var uri = new Uri("microsoft.windows.camera.picker:");
        var result = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriForResultsAsync(uri, _launcherOptions, set);
        if (result.Status == LaunchUriStatus.Success && result.Result != null)
        {
            return tempFile;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

And using it like this:

```cs
public async Task<FileResult> CaptureAsync(MediaPickerOptions options, bool photo)
{
    var captureUi = new CameraCaptureUI(options);

    var file = await captureUi.CaptureFileAsync(photo ? CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo : CameraCaptureUIMode.Video);

    if (file != null)
        return new FileResult(file.Path,file.ContentType);

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Gerald, Your help was much appreciated to implement this code!!

Comment: Gerald would this be something that you could make a video about?

Comment: What is it you can't figure out?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working. result is always Unknown, using the exact code from your answer.

Comment: Open the issues on GitHub that I have linked. Still open, no update to share unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I used this workaround in my app and it works perfectly.  It includes a sample app to show how it is integrated.

https://github.com/richardrigutins/maui-sample-windows-camera-workaround

You basically grab the CustomMediaPicker files in each of the Platforms folders and copy them to your corresponding folders.  You may want to change the using namespace in each file.  You will also need to copy the CustomMediaPicker.cs that has the partial class CustomMediaPicker : IMediaPicker and is used in your app instead of MediaPicker.Default.  When you want to use the CustomMediaPicker where ever you were previously using MediaPicker.Default.

private readonly IMediaPicker _mediaPicker = new CustomMediaPicker();